# How to write $\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n $ in terms of Stirling numbers of the first kind?

Tags: derivatives, summation, stirling-numbers

How to write $\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n $ in terms of Stirling numbers of the first kind ${n\brack m}$?

I know that we can write the above in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind ${n\brace m}$,

as below:

$$\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n=\sum_{m=1}^n {n\brace m} x^m \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^m, \qquad n \ge 1.$$

Is there a similar way of writing this for the Stirling numbers of the first kind ${n\brack m}$?

Comment: Your relation is for every $l \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ :  $\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^nx^l =(\sum_{m=1}^n \left\{\matrix{ n \\ m}\right\}x^m (\frac{d}{dx})^m) x^l$. Then use $(x \frac{d}{dx})^n x^l = l^n x^l, x^m (\frac{d}{dx})^m x^l = (l)_m x^l, (x(\frac{d}{dx})^m x^{m-1}) x^l = (l)^m x^l$ and the definitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number#Expansions_of_falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: @reuns Thank you. But I did not understand. I think to use the Stirling numbers of the first kind we have to write the dual of the above formula. That means we have to write $x^n \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n$  in terms of $\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^m$. I don`t know how to apply your method.