# Simplifying the differential operator $\left(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} \right)^nf(z)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, operator-theory

I have been playing around with differential operators and was able to prove the following operator identities via induction on $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}z \right)^nf(z) &=z^n\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dz^n}z^n f(z),\\
\left(z^2\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\right)^nf(z) &=z^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dz^n}z^{n-1} f(z),\\
\left(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}+\omega\right)\left(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}+\omega-1\right)\cdots \left(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}+\omega-(n-1)\right)f(z) &=z^{n-\omega}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dz^n}z^\omega f(z).
\end{align}
$$
However, when considering the operator $\left(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\right)^n$, I find no way to simplify it in terms of products of powers of $z$ and $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}$.

> Is there a way to simplify
> $$
> \left(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\right)^nf(z)
> $$
> in terms of products of powers of $z$ and $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}$?

Comment: A representation of $\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^n$ in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind is given *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092596)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is nothing simpler than this
$$
\left(z \frac{d}{dz}\right)^n f(z) =
\sum_{k=1}^n \left\{n\atop k\right\} z^k \frac{d^k}{dz^k} f(z)
$$
where $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number)

Comment: Thank you.  I was aware of this identity.  I do marvel at the fact that $(z^2\partial_z)^n$ admits such a simple form yet $(z\partial_z)^n$ appears not to.

Comment: Prof. Edgar, in regards to the identities I posted in my question, do you know of any sources that have already derived them or identities similar to them? I am certain I'm not the first one to find them but haven't come up with much searching the internet. Even some keywords to do further searching would be very helpful.